# Android keeps loosing Launch Defaults, app settings and installed updates and installed apps after every reboot

Tags: settings, reboot, twrp, default-applications, google-apps

After every reboot Android keeps loosing Launch Defaults, some app settings and even some of installed updates and installed apps.

I re-flashed the stock firmware, then applied all the OTA updates. After that I only flashed TWRP, GApps (Pico Uni) and SuperSU.

Given this, I tried several Factory Resets (from Settings), but every time, after installing some number of apps, some of the above start disappearing with every reboot. As I varied the sequence of apps installed, the data lost is every time something else. Examples from different Factory Resets include:

- lost default app for search on Home button tap-and-drag
- lost default app for browser
- lost Gmail preferences (Global ones) and/or account Sync flag
- updates of Motorola Camera and Motorola Gallery (via Play Store)
- some of apps I just installed (via Play Store) disappear after reboot
- internal storage becomes read-only for apps (even rooted ones), but remains writable for Android File Transfer

What I tried so far:

- erasing cache and dalvik cache--actually after nearly every app installed, and of course after Factory Reset
- uninstalling and reinstalling every app in question
- manual resetting app defaults in Settings>Apps, both globally and for individual apps
- none of the apps installed to SD / internal storage, so it shouldn't be an issue

What I didn't try include:

- erasing internal storage and SD card (most apps were previously "moved to SD")
- whatever reformatting or repartitioning the Android partitions

Any ideas what to try next?

I have Moto G 2nd gen (XT1079 dual-SIM). It runs Android auto-updated from stock 5.0.2 22.36.1 (build LXB22.99-7.1) to stock Lollipop 5.0.2 22.46.7 (build LXB22.99-24.7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause was a wrong edition of TWRP: I mistakenly downloaded TWRP for Titan series of Moto G 2, while my XT1079 phone is obviously part of Thea series.

Discovered that through trial-and-error in several other re-installs of the original ROM, GApps, TWRP and OTAs.